# The vanishing of homotopy invariant $K$-theory of dg-categories

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, differential-graded-algebras, motives

In my previous question [The vanishing of non-connective K-theory in negative degrees](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74237/the-vanishing-of-non-connective-k-theory-in-negative-degrees)
I asked when one can be sure that the negative non-connective $K$-groups of a differential graded category vanish. Now, does the situation become simpler if one considers the homotopy invariant $K$-theory (so, one replaces the spectrum $\mathcal{K}(X)$ by $\operatorname{holim}_nK(X\times \Delta_n)$)?